# R: Apply function to last level of nested list and keep name & structure

Tags: r, list

```
m <- matrix(1:9, ncol=3)
list1 <- vector("list", 3)
list1 <- lapply(list1, function(x) x <- m)
list2 <- vector("list", 3)
list2 <- lapply(list2, function(x) x <- list1)
list2
```

I would like to get an object with the same structure as `list2`, which contains the return of a  function of the matrix (in my case colMeans). This should work with up to n dimensions.

I was playing around with nesting lapply, but it doesn't keep the names and I am sure somebody here knows a smarter way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you are looking for `rapply`

Comment: Thanks! Can you elaborate a bit? Using `rapply(list2, colMeans)` gives me a vector - so all structure is lost. edit: got it, thanks! `rapply(list2, colMeans, how = "list")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rapply(list2, colMeans, how="replace")
```

Comment: `> identical(rapply(list2, colMeans, how="list"),rapply(list2, colMeans, how="replace"))
[1] TRUE`